# Access children DIVs in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, show

I have a structure, such as

```
<div class="entry">
     <p class="entry-text"><div class="nonmatched-sentence">some text goes here...</div></p>
</div>
```

how do I show all the nonmatched-sentence elements if they were made invisible before?

I now use this:

```
$(this).('entry-text').children('.nonmatched-sentence').show();
```

But it's not working...

Thanks!

Comment: On what event should de open?

Comment: `.find('.entry-text')` you were  missing a period and you need to use a method to filter the element you wish to target, sch as `.find()`

Answer (score 0):

You could go with this approach: http://jsfiddle.net/oejm2wfu/

For example I have created an event on the button click:

```
$("#btn").click(function(){

    $(".nonmatched-sentence").each(function(){
   $(this).show(); 
});

});
```

but you could do that on any event you want. Hope that helps